Symfony 5.3 deprecation: from `SessionInterface` to `RequestStack->getSession()`, but throws `SessionNotFoundException`
On a Symfony 5.4 project, I am trying to get rid of this deprecation

Since symfony/framework-bundle 5.3: The "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface" and "SessionInterface" aliases are deprecated, use "$requestStack->getSession()" instead.

I followed the official doc for service, so
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class SomeService
{
    public function __construct(private RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
        $session->get("...");
    }
}

instead of the previous version that was
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SomeService
{
    public function __construct(private SessionInterface $session)
    {
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->session->get("...");
    }
}

but this fails with SessionNotFoundException and error

There is currently no session available.

it seems that the RequestStack that the dependency injector injects inside the service has no Session available.

it may depend on where you are trying to use the service SomeService you've created. If you are calling it from a CLI context, that usually doesn't have a session, so it should fail.

I didn't downvote your question. Think about what a session is - it is a function of a web browser - a web browser is not in use when using a CLI command, so the session isn't available at all.

@craigh yes, I understand your point. But the official doc explains how to use session inside a service through RequestStack. It doesn't seem to prohibit this in a CLI environment. If so I would expect a note inside the doc, or that the service is somehow reserved for Controllers only... I am confused

You need to define $session as a property and set it in your constructor, here is how to do so:
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SomeService
{
    private SessionInterface $session;
    
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->session = $requestStack->getSession();
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->session->get("...");
    }
}


Doesn't solve the problem and is discouraged by the official doc. Accessing the session in the constructor is NOT recommended, since it might not be accessible yet or lead to unwanted side-effects

Alright, sorry then, you're right. Didn't know that point.
